# tiptap prosemirror should only specific nodes editable

Tags: javascript, prose-mirror, tiptap

i try to make an editor with tiptap (prosemirror) where all content not editable by default.
Only my custom nodes (for example `<var-input>`) should be editable.

For example:

```
<p>This is a non editable text</p><p><var-input id="12345" kind="{}" choices="[]" value="">This <strong>is</strong> editable</var-input></p><p>This also not editable.</p>
```

Only the content between the tags `<var-input ...>` and `</var-input>` should be editable.

How can i do that?

I use tiptap, that is build on top of prosemirror for vue.js.

Answer (score 3):

Try setting [`atom: true`](https://prosemirror.net/docs/ref/#model.NodeSpec.atom) in your custom nodes' spec.

> Can be set to true to indicate that, though this isn't a leaf node, it doesn't have directly editable content and should be treated as a single unit in the view.